# The source folder "c:\test\test" of the synchronized folder "APPDIR" is missing from disk error in advanced installer jenkins plug in build

Tags: jenkins, advanced-installer

We are using advanced installer 9.7 .

We are using Jenkins to create builds but we are facing the below issue with jenkins plug in-

I tried all online resources but had no luck please help to fix this.

Running as SYSTEM
Building on master in workspace D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\jobname
$ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\caphyon.jenkins.advinst.AdvinstInstallation\Advanced_Installer_-*app\bin\x86\AdvancedInstaller.com" /Register ********
[jobname] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\caphyon.jenkins.advinst.AdvinstInstallation\Advanced_Installer*-_app\bin\x86\AdvancedInstaller.com" /execute "C:\Source\Advanced Installer\projectname.aip" "D:\JenkinsWorkspaces\foldername\aic8583942971418633890aic"

Comment: The error is - The source folder "some remotepath" of the synchronized folder "APPDIR" is missing from disk. You need to either recreate the source folder path or reset the synchronization from the "Folder Properties" dialog, in "Synchronize" tab.Build step 'Invoke Advanced Installer' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Advanced Installer' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Have you tried to check that the related source folder ("some remotepath") does exist and is accessible for the user account (SYSTEM) under which the Jenkins build run? You should make sure that System user account has access on your remote path that is synchronized with the "Application Folder" directory from "Files and Folders" page of your setup project.

Comment: Thank you All...Yes it is related to the access issue for the Jenkins job, But I was confused with the Error...Then what we did is instead of using files from the remote path,we moved files to the server where jenkins installed and did sync with the local path from files and folders section which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding the "clean" options when running the build, solved the issue.